# Regular expression escaping tab key

Tags: javascript

Hi I want to allow alphanumeric + _ in a text box. but when I press tab it warns me about the special characters are not allowed. Here is the Javascript code. Is there a way to escape tab and carriage return using regular expressions ?

```
function splChars(str)
{
if (str != "")
{
    if (/^[\w _\t\r]+$/.test(str))
        return true;
     else
        return false;
}
}
```

Comment: When you say "it warns me", who is "it"? Can you please give more context?

Comment: You can't enter a tab into a textbox, tab takes you out of the textbox.

Comment: If it's empty and you press tab, the textbox stays empty and will not match the regexp due to the `+`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
.replace(/([^a-z0-9_])/gi, '\\$1');
```

eg:

```
'abd12^_$'.replace(/([^a-z0-9_])/gi, '\\$1') // "abd12\^_\$"
```

Comment: After typing text in a textbox when I click tab, the above function returns false, means it takes tab key as character. I am using this function on keyup event on a text box. Basically I just want user to enter alphnumeric + _ or space characters. and as soon as user finished typing , he/she can use tab key to move onto next text box.